# Link a div to content

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I have made a 3d Hover effect for a Team Members about page. When you hover over a photo it flips like a box and reveals peoples credentials. I want to be able to make the div link to the team members content (the page that goes further into depth about each individual team member). I have re-written the code like so:

[field_photo]

```
     <a href="[node:content]"><div class="ch-info-back">
        <br/> <br/>
           <h3> [title] </h3>
              <p> [field_position] </p>
  </div></a>
```

I tried linking it like:  . Unfortunately, no luck... I saw that I could make a php function but there must be an easier way !! if anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated (=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field to your view of type `Content:Path` and drag it to the top of your field list. Then your href should be:

```
<a href="[path]"><div class="ch-info-back">
```